# How to use Regex.Replace in different scenarios

Tags: c#, regex

I had a similar question up before but wasn't able to actually get the correct answer in the end.

I have a function that takes what I write in an input field and matches it with what I get back from the database. It also takes a parameter that is always "em".

The function looks like this:

```
public static string Hightlight(this string input, string phrase, string tag)
    {
        foreach (var item in phrase.Split(' '))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
                continue;

            input = Regex.Replace(input,
                string.Format("(?<phrase>{0})", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item)),
                string.Format("<{0}>${{phrase}}</{0}>", tag), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }

return input
}
```

This has been working until people tried writing, for example, `Martina E`.
The regexp then tries to match the E with ALL the e's in the input I'm building with the `<em>`-tags.

Is there a better way to do this?
I want the input end result to be something like this: `<em>Martina</em><em>E</em>`

Comment: Yes, do not use REGEX on Tagged data that is not regular.  Regex (Regular expression) should not be used for tagged data.  Instead use a library that is designed for the tag language that you are using.

Comment: So, what are the requirements? You just take some user input, split it with space and replace each of these items with the wrapped version.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew pretty much, first itteration in the foreach loop, i replace the old input with something like < em > Martina </ em> E. Second one i match all E in that one with the E i have in my input field... which makes it have like em in the em, if you understand what im saying? Only requirment is that i cant use a library in this case

Comment: @jdweng no outer library is okey in this case

Comment: I edited the question, but I do not understand what your input looks like.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh sorry, i probably said it incorrectly... the PHRASE is what i write into the field. Its what i want to fetch from the database. Could be Martina V Hesin or whatever name i actually wanna search for.

The input is what i get back from the database, the diffrent names that could be related to "Martina V Hesin" or similar. Its also the input i return back to my view later on so i can render my highlighted result. this is the string we manipulate in the function to add em tags to

Comment: Ok, that's a bit too verbose. Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
https://gyazo.com/ffb0b947c7f3058bd09760cf83ff86bd?token=0a63c3a6b7a8c43e71b3061d7b3bb966

Thats the search view. phrase paramter is what you write into the input-field.
input paramter is Emma Johansson.

But after we've gone through the function/regex, it looks like the result under the input box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a single regex for the regex replace that will match the names as whole words outside of the tags:

```
return Regex.Replace(
            input, 
            string.Format(@"(<{0}>.*?</{0}>)|(?<!\w)(?:{1})(?!\w)", tag,
                string.Join("|", 
                    phrase.Trim().Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(x => Regex.Escape(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(x)))
                )
            ), 
            m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", tag, m.Value), 
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
        );
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/zfKuvQ)

In short:

- `(<{0}>.*?</{0}>)|(?<!\w)(?:{1})(?!\w)` will result in a regex like `(<em>.*?</em>)|(?<!\w)(?:Emma|E)(?!\w)` that will match `Emma` or `E` that are not enclosed with word chars or a substring between `<em>` and `</em>` capturing the latter in Group 1
- `phrase.Trim().Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => Regex.Escape(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(x))))` splits the `phrase` with spaces removing empty items, escapes each item for use in a regex pattern with `Regex.Escape` after encoding for HTML, and then
- `string.Join("|", ...)` joins the items with a pipe char.
- `m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", tag, m.Value)` replaces with the Group 1 contents (the existing tagged text) if Group 1 matched, else, the tagged match is added.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed! Thanks!